# Why does Valgrind reports an invalid free() after a realloc()?

Tags: c, free, valgrind, realloc

When I run valgrind on the following (example) code it reports an "Invalid free() / delete / delete[]" and Invalids reads. I really can't understand why. Can somebody please explain ?

Edit : Thanks for your replies, it's so obvious now.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h

void vl_dec(char* a) {
  char* str = a;
  while (*(str+1) != '\0') str++;
  while(*str == '0') {
    *str = '9';
    str--;
  }
  (*str)--;

  if (*a == '0') {
    memmove(a, a+1, strlen(a));
    a = (char*)realloc(a, (strlen(a)+1)*sizeof(char));
    if (a == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate memory\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  char* a = (char*)malloc(6*sizeof(char));
  if (a == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate memory\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  strcpy(a, "10000");
  vl_dec(a);
  printf("%s\n", a);
  free(a);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your function `main`, you are passing `a` to `vl_dec` by value, so it never gets updated - the result of `realloc` is only stored in a local variable that's lost when `vl_dec` returns. Instead, pass its address:

```
void vl_dec(char ** a) { *a = realloc(...); }

int main()
{
    char * a = malloc(...);
    vl_dec(&a);
    free(a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't just assume that the new value of `a` that `realloc` returns is the same as the old value. You actually have to update the pointer every where it's used. I suspect you know that, because you correctly saved the return value of `realloc` inside of `vl_dec`, however you forgot that you need to return the new value of `a` from `vl_dec` (or update it by using a `char**` as the paramter to `vl_dec`.)

Answer (score 0):

because you pass the pointer to `vl_dec` by value, not by reference.

If you `realloc` the pointer within `vl_dec` your main function will still see the original pointer declared in main. After `realloc` that pointer is invalid, so valgrind complains.

A easy way to fix this is to rewrite `vl_dec` and let it return the pointer. That way you can call:

```
   a = vl_dec(a);
```

In main and the problem is solved.